# Tooltipster from large elements on my page is not visible when the page is already scrolled up or down

Tags: jquery, tooltipster

Tooltipster is intended to add information concerning some large images on my page, but it displays on top or on bottom of most images, often not within the visible part of the browser window. Then it can't be seen when the page is already scrolled down or up even a little bit. With horizontal scrolls it displays always inside the visible part of the window.

I don't know how to get the Tooltipster content visible when the top or the bottom of the image is not displayed. With text links everything is at about OK although the automated change from bottom to top at the upper or lower margin does not always take place. The default tooltips of many browsers show information of a title statement from the img src tag close to the cursor beyond to the right or above the mouse tip even if only a part of an image is hovered over. A similar default mode I would like most.

Now I found out, that Tooltipster executes the align statements of the img src tag such as left, right, top, bottom or middle if any. The default tooltips of the browsers ignore that.

I am not able to run the proposed method reposition to fix the position like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.tooltip').tooltipster({ theme: 'tooltipster-light', delay: [500,0], delayTouch: [0,6000], timer: 12000, distance: 1, side: 'bottom' });
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster({ functionBefore: function(instance, helper) { instance.reposition;} });
    });
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Try to reposition the tooltip with the dedicated method once the image is loaded.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with the dedicated method?

Comment: I tried to use the method reposition in the way I added meanwhile to my post, but didn't get it to work like this. How has this method to be used?